# How to print qlist for below piece of code

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QList < class >` type . I want to print the Qlist how can i do it??

Declaration of QList:

```cpp
QList < SidSafetyPacketIn > a_safetyPackets;
```

Now Data appended for QList like below:

```cpp
a_safetyPackets.append(SidSafetyPacketIn(pSpdFrom1To4Model, expectedSids[i], i));
```

Now if i want to print the above QList how to do it?

Comment: One way is to [override the `qDebug()` stream operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#providing-support-for-the-qdebug-stream-operator). Then you can use `qDebug` to print the list to your console.

Comment: `QList` supports `begin` and `end`; you should be able to use it in an ordinary range based for-loop. Within, you'd choose the formatting that appears appropriate to you for the safety packet objects. Where do you want to print to? Still console or to a GUI field (as QT is a GUI framework). The former, you can do directly, the latter, you could build up a string and assign it to a QLabel or QTextField.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate over a `QList`, or are you asking how to print an individual `SidSafeteyPacketIn`?

Answer (score 3):

If the SidSafetyPacketIn class is printable,you can print QList simply use foreach() function,a example like this:

```
QList<QString>lst;
lst.append("haha");
lst.append("bigg");
foreach(auto &x,lst)
    qDebug()<<x;
```

and the output is:

```
"haha"
"bigg"
```